# How to use contactRepository in Sitecore 9.3 analytics

Tags: xdb, xconnect, experience-analytics

I am working on XDB analytics code upgrade from Sitecore 8.2 to Sitecore 9.3

Some of the xdb repository not working in Sitecore 9.3 analytics.

For Example :tracking/contactRepository, tracking/contactManager as shown below

```
public void MergeTwoKnownContacts(string dyingContactIdentity, Contact survivingContact)
    {
        if (survivingContact == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(dyingContactIdentity))
            return;

        ContactRepository ContactRepository = Factory.CreateObject("tracking/contactRepository", true) as ContactRepository;

        Contact dyingContact = GetContact(dyingContactIdentity, "Contact Merge");

        if (ContactRepository != null && dyingContact != null)
        {
            // The data will be transferred from the dyingContact to the survivingContact
            ContactRepository.MergeContacts(survivingContact, dyingContact);
        }
    }
```

As per my understating "tracking/contactRepository" and tracking/contactManager would not be support in Sitecore 9.x. I Would like to understand What is the replacement of the repository in Sitecore 9.x analytics.

Appreciated someone help to understand. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

The `ContactRepository` should not be used in Sitecore 9+ to modify a contact that does not have an ongoing session, use the `xConnect Client API`. From your `MergeTwoKnownContacts` method, it looks like you are merging two contacts. To merge an existing source contact into an existing target contact, you should use the `client.MergeContacts()` method. Contacts are merged by the xConnect service layer after `Submit()` / `SubmitAsync()` has been called.

```
public void ExampleSync()
        {
            using (Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClient client = Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    // New known contact
                    var identifers = new ContactIdentifier[] { new ContactIdentifier("twitter", "myrtlesitecore", ContactIdentifierType.Known) };

                    var newContact = new Contact(identifers);

                    client.AddContact(newContact);

                    // Contact must be saved before a merge
                    client.Submit();

                    // Reference to existing contact
                    var reference = new Sitecore.XConnect.ContactReference(Guid.Parse("B9814105-1F45-E611-82E6-34E6D7117DCB"));

                    Contact existingContact = client.Get<Sitecore.XConnect.Contact>(reference, new Sitecore.XConnect.ContactExpandOptions() { });

                    // Data copied FROM existingContact TO newContact
                    client.MergeContacts(existingContact, newContact);

                    client.Submit();

                }
                catch (XdbExecutionException ex)
                {
                    // Manage exceptions
                }
            }
        }
```

above is a sync example for contact merge. Sitecore has very good documentation for the merge contact with merge logic - https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/sitecore-experience-platform/en/merge-contacts.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below to get the contactManager.

```
ContactManager _contactManager = Factory.CreateObject("tracking/contactManager", true) as ContactManager;
```

Then you can use the below line to get the contact from **ContactManager**

```
var contact = _contactManager.LoadContact(Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId);
```

Hope this helps.